SwiftUI NavigationSplitView and Keyboard avoidance
Once again pulling my hair out over SwiftUI. Here's a NavigationStackView that looks great until the keyboard comes up.
NavigationSplitView {
    NavigationStack {
        Navigation()
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
            .listStyle(.sidebar)
        }
    } detail: {
        GalacticMap()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
            .toolbar {
                GalacticMapToolbar()
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(mapController)
    }

Looks fine until the keyboard comes up, then it inexplicably slides over to the right in order to keep the aspect ratio. How do I just make the keyboard slide over the content?!
See the video below for what actually happens: https://i.imgur.com/YbL93pm.mp4, but a GIF is attached.

